# Autovacuum - database

Tags: database

Does anyone know what autovacuum means in the sense of databases?

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: Why not? It seems to be a matter that is unique to the programming profession.

Comment: it is programming related. I'm trying to understand SQLJet and there are many autovacuum expressions in the code...

Comment: SO is for programming questions; it is not a dictionary service!

Answer (score 1):

Specific to [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/routine-vacuuming.html) it means:

> PostgreSQL's VACUUM command has to run
>   on a regular basis for several
>   reasons:
>
> 1.To recover or reuse disk space occupied by updated or deleted rows.
>
> 2.To update data statistics used by the PostgreSQL query planner.
>
> 3.To protect against loss of very old data due to transaction ID wraparound.

Answer (score 1):

On Google App Engine this refers to the Indexes (you vacuum an index, meaning you remove it).

On Postgre it refers to tidying up the database table (garbage collection and optimisation).

An autovacuum daemon waits until there are no transactions and then dives in to perform the vacuum operation.

Answer (score 1):

In postgres the `AUTOVACUUM` refers to regular maintenance tasks:

- To recover disk space occupied by updated or deleted rows.
- To update data statistics used by the PostgreSQL query planner.
- To protect against loss of very old data due to transaction ID wraparound.

See: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/maintenance.html